# Typescript discriminated union narrowing not working

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I have the following (simplified) code where I am trying to use discriminated union type. When I try to access `data` TS thinks it may be `undefined` and I am not sure why.

```js
type Return =
  | {
    isReady: 'yes';
    data: { a: number };
  }
  | {
    isReady: 'no';
    data: false;
  };

const myFunction = (): Return => {
  return {
    isReady: 'yes',
    data: { a: 111 }
  };
}

const { isReady, data } = myFunction()

if (isReady === 'yes') {
  const { a } = data; // ERROR: Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a: number; } | undefined'.
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By destructuring the the discriminated union result of `myFunction()`, you have unfortunately destroyed any correlation the compiler could see between the `isReady` and the `data` properties:

```
const { isReady, data } = myFunction()
// const isReady: "yes" | "no"
// const data: false | {  a: number; }
```

Here, `isReady` and `data` are seen by the compiler to both be of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), each with two members.  That's not *wrong*, but the compiler now only sees the pair of `isReady` and `data` as having essentially *four* possible members:

```
const oops: (
    | { isReady: "yes", data: false }
    | { isReady: "no", data: false }
    | { isReady: "yes", data: { a: number } }
    | { isReady: "no", data: { a: number } }
) = { isReady, data }
```

And so checking `isReady` has no implication on `data` that the compiler can keep track of.

---

This limitation in TypeScript's support for what I've been calling *correlated union types* is the subject of the feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  TypeScript 4.4 has introduced [support for aliased conditions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730)) where you can store something like `isReady` into a variable and the compiler will use it later to discriminate your union:

```
const result = myFunction();
const isReady = result.isReady;

if (isReady === 'yes') {
    const { a } = result.data; // okay in TypeScript 4.4
}
```

but [as noted here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730#issuecomment-896204885),

> the pattern of destructuring a discriminant property and a payload property into two local variables and expecting a coupling between the two is not supported as the control flow analyzer doesn't "see" the connection. For example:
>
> ```
> type Data = { kind: 'str', payload: string } | { kind: 'num', payload: number };
>
> function foo({ kind, payload }: Data) {
>     if (kind === 'str') {
>         payload.length;  // Error, payload not narrowed to string
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> We may be able to support that pattern later, but likely not in this PR.

So for now there's no way to do this.

---

The most plausible way forward for now is just not to destructure at all, and use discriminated unions the way they were meant to be used, as single objects with a discriminant property:

```
const result = myFunction();
if (result.isReady === 'yes') {
    const { a } = result.data; // okay
}
```

And I'll add this to the growing list of issues at microsoft/TypeScript#30581.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7KBeAUFHUA+UA3trqQJYDOcAhgCYgBcUA5CBBcwNwmk63XBqTQlCFQUCALYAjCEigBfbqQU98RNeSoQ6jFigD2XTbn6CmAM2oAbChGW4lmTAGMDKCsCiSQAMQQoLsBk7hhQABQAlExwiKgYAHwapEjwyGjEvLiUNPRMrOzMADQmfAJiImIAjDWKak6qmCjUkuxg1C7QAHIGkMm4bh5eIjk69EVQZtSKYT7+gcHuUWoA9CtQg55Qo7pMAERsFHvqe4Z7q+ubXlOWNnbqIqJMEjJynHVqV1AGvRRM4aUHtttLsoAd2HsJjcoFZbNBVFkcAQRiC8mCzlDyrc4XVEUCdmjwUdMeYiE9xFJZPIFLjEcjgbk9KcDJDJliyWIXlSZgjcJEwijGSTpqpGs1WhR2p0oABhawGOzyYifdxbVIUBDWLzobx+AJBEIoKIOHBfAkgMLqzXAAB05u4ajIFgi5ow6B1BQ4-MyiK+lRmOqtWptU3ea2+AGtqBayGgACrgCAAZRcSDIYC8ABYbZn6pgxS02h1oAB1AxICMUDQqoZQIPa3XzA1LSIm7bO8L1u2oi3uj2HZjewF+0QBuvsa0h8ph9YGKMgPP5oA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, Joe. Stay safe ❤️ 

Comment: Beautifully explained....  had been struggling for quite some time before stumbling upon this response. **Thank you!!**

Answer (score 0):

### **You could try to check for `data` type instead:**

```
type Return =
  {
    isReady: 'yes';
    data: { a: number };
  }
  | {
    isReady: 'no';
    data: false;
  };

const myFunction = (): Return => {
  return {
    isReady: 'yes',
    data: { a: 111 }
  };
}

const { isReady, data } = myFunction()

if (typeof data !== 'boolean') {
  const { a } = data;
}
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7KBeAUFKBvbOUAlgM5wCGAJiAFxQDkIEJ9A3ATpecOXblLygoEAWwBGEJFAC%207HNIIAfPB2JkIVWgxQB7Nqq486AM3IAbEhDkz2mAMY6UJYFBEgAYghR3gRRxigACgBKOjhEVAwAPhUcJHhkNHxCNQpqOkZmegAaA25BfkEARhKZAllMBXtHZzxUjWpsqENyGQC3T29fRxDMTCJjINBIHUGWqABCdHQGMR0dMw0UemDYqAcnF0K2mZb2aSA)

Comment: I guess some of the intent got lost when I simplified my original code :) Originally, `isReady` is a boolean and `data` maybe an object or `undefined`. If `isReady` is `true` then it's an object, otherwise it's `undefined`. I already do checks on `isReady` so doubling up and checking `data` defeats the purpose for me.